# Printer Canon d440 is not working

Tags: printer

I'm trying to print with my printer **Canon pc-d440**. I plug in it into the computer and it install the driver without problem. However when i try to print something, nothing happend. The status of printer is idle and i cannot try to print test page because it is grayed out. The question is can i print with this printer on Linux optionally on Elementary OS? And if yes, how?

Thank you for answers and sorry for my English.